# Xorg pointer options not taking effect

Tags: xorg, udev, mouse, input, xinput

My acceleration (and other) pointer settings are not taking effect.

Xorg.0.log shows the following:

```
[ 16276.122] (**) Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Applying InputClass "TrackPointClass"
[ 16276.122] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)'
```

That's what I expected to see. The "TrackPointClass" (which I wrote) contains the following acceleration settings:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "TrackPointClass"
  MatchProduct    "TrackPoint"
  MatchIsPointer  "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Driver          "evdev"
    Option     "Evdev Wheel Emulation" "1"
    Option     "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" "2"
    Option     "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" "200"
    Option     "Device Accel Profile" "5"
    Option     "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" "3.7"
    Option     "Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration" "4.7"
    Option     "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" "200"
    Option     "GrabDevice" "yes"
EndSection
```

According to the above lines from Xorg.0.log, my settings should be applied... they are not.

The log continues:

```
[ 16276.123] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event7 13:71 fd 39 paused 0
[ 16276.123] (**) Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): always reports core events
[ 16276.123] (**) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Device: "/dev/input/event7"
[ 16276.198] (--) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Vendor 0x6cb Product 0x9
[ 16276.198] (--) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Found 3 mouse buttons
[ 16276.198] (--) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Found relative axes
[ 16276.198] (--) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Found x and y relative axes
[ 16276.198] (--) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Found absolute axes
[ 16276.198] (II) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[ 16276.198] (II) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): Configuring as mouse
[ 16276.198] (**) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[ 16276.198] (**) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
```

The above EmulateWheelButton: 4 is not what I set... I set 2
And the next line below indicates (to me) that udev configs are possibly being applied (and overwriting anything previously applied?)

```
[ 16276.198] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14.4/1-14.4:1.1/input/input7/event7"
```

Notice below that the acceleration profile is not what is specified in "TrackPointClass". None of the other acceleration values are what is specified either.

```
[ 16276.198] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[ 16276.198] (II) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): initialized for relative axes.
[ 16276.198] (WW) evdev: Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): ignoring absolute axes.
[ 16276.198] (**) Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 16276.198] (**) Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): (accel) acceleration profile 0
[ 16276.198] (**) Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 16276.198] (**) Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick): (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 16276.199] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick) (/dev/input/mouse2)
```

After starting KDE, the TrackPoint has none of my acceleration config values and middle button scrolling does not work.

I can get it working by running this script, which has the same contents as my "TrackPointClass" listed above. However, I prefer not to do that workaround, as my settings are lost every time I switch to a virtual console. I am looking for a persistent solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Device Accel Profile" "5"
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" "3.7"
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration" "4.7"
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" "200"
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Evdev Wheel Emulation" "1"
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Button" "2"
xinput set-prop "Synaptics Inc. Composite TouchPad / TrackPoint (Stick)" "Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout" "200"
```

As a test, I moved /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf to 40-libinput.conf.save. This didn't help. My "TrackPointClass" is defined in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-trackpoint.conf for now. I previously had it in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-trackpoint.conf. Neither location proved to resolve my issue.

### Questions:

1. Why is the xorg configuration not being applied?
2. How do I fix it?
3. optional: where are these default rules / config settings coming from?

#### Background:

I prefer to use the evdev driver to get the acceleration I need. In my experience libinput does not suffice for a TrackPoint used with 3 high resolution monitors. With libinput my mouse is too fast for fine work and much too slow for moving around my screen real estate.

I'm running Arch Linux with KDE

#### Update:

This doesn't work either:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "TrackPointClass"
  MatchProduct    "TrackPoint"
  MatchIsPointer  "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Driver          "evdev"
    Option     "WheelEmulation" "1"
    Option     "WheelEmulationButton" "2"
    Option     "WheelEmulationTimeout" "200"
    Option     "DeviceAccelProfile" "5"
    Option     "DeviceAccelConstantDeceleration" "3.7"
    Option     "DeviceAccelAdaptiveDeceleration" "4.7"
    Option     "DeviceAccelVelocityScaling" "200"
    Option     "GrabDevice" "yes"
EndSection
```

Comment: All the Options in your `TrackPointClass` should be written without spaces.

Comment: @dirkt - writing the options without spaces gives an error for each option like this: property 'EvdevWheelEmulationTimeout' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format

Comment: You also have to use the correct names :-) See `man evdev`: `EmulateWheel`, `EmulateWheelButton`, etc.

Comment: @dirkt do you see any problems with my updated conf? (See update section in my question). Still not working. Thanks for any help.

Comment: No resolution yet.